# How to apply key function on tuple elems in sorted()?

Tags: function, sorting, python-3.x, tuples

We know both of this works for sorted():

```
sorted(['second', 'first', 'third'])
sorted([('first','second'), ('second', 'first'), ('first', 'third')])
```

By sorting the second one, the tuples are compared lexicographically; the first items are compared; if they are the same then the second items are compared, and so on.

But how to apply a key function on all the individual strings (or anything else there) for sorted which works for both containers and works recursively in the second case? Let's say func converts 'first' to 3, 'second' to 1 and 'third' to 2. I want this result:

```
['second', 'third', 'first']
[('second', 'first'), ('first','second'), ('first', 'third')]
```

I made this function to use as key but I dont like typechecking in it since it applies func only on strings which is not a general solution:

```
def recursively_apply_func_on_strings(target, func,
    fargs=(), fkwargs={}):
    if isinstance(target, str):
        return func(target, *fargs, **fkwargs)       
    result, f = [], recursively_apply_func_on_strings
    for elem in target:
        result.append(f(elem, func, fargs, fkwargs))
    return tuple(result)

sorted(sequence, key=lambda x: recursively_apply_string_func(x, func))
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's any better algorithm than what you have. You might make the code a bit nicer using a generator expression inside the `tuple` constructor, rather than appending the values to result one by one, but that's the only thing I can see to improve. If you don't like the check for `str`, consider making it call `func` on any string, or anything that is not iterable (you want to exclude strings from the recursive case, since they're recursively iterable forever). Use `isinstance(target, collections.Iterable)` to test for iterable types.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on that, sometimes I miss to use them, the generator expressions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, despite my comment saying otherwise, I think there are a few possible ways to improve things.

One idea is to make your function a key-function factory. This way you won't need a lambda to apply it with extra arguments in your `sorted` call.

Another idea is to apply `func` to all non-iterable values (plus strings), using the abstract `Iterable` type from the `collections` module to test against.

Here's some code:

```
from collections import Iterable

def recursive_key(func, fargs=(), fkwargs={}):
    def key_func(target):
        if isinstance(target, str) or not isinstance(target, Iterable):
            return func(target, *fargs, **fkwargs)       
        return tuple(key_func(item) for item in target)
    return key_func
```

You'd call it like this (sorting by hexidecimal integer value, rather than string value):

```
sorted([('a', 'F'), ('A', 'd')], key=recursive_key(int, (16,)))
```

Note that we're *calling* `recursive_key` and it's return value (a.k.a. `key_func`) is what is being passed as the `key` parameter to `sorted`.

Comment: Thanks for your nice code! The only alteration I made was replacing `tuple` with `target.__class__` so it works nicely on lists aswell.